# How to display special characters from JSON data in html?

Tags: javascript, html

in json file: `{"Name":"Sundar &#x27; pichai","Company":"Google"}`

in HTML I want like this: Sundar'Pichai

Comment: `thatJSON['Name']` would return what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.innerHTML` at this context, `&#x27;` This character code will be converted into its mapped character when you use `.innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = thatJSON['Name'];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use in AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-bind-html` directive if you want to do in angularJS way

[ng-bind-html-ref doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

[plunkr-example](http://plnkr.co/edit/M1woXS)